# Extract Data from JSON Array in Flutter/Dart

Tags: json, parsing, dart, flutter

This is the response from request.

```
var response = [{"id":4731},{"id":4566},{"id":4336},{"id":4333},{"id":4172},{"id":4170},{"id":4168},{"id":4166},{"id":4163},{"id":4161}];
```

How to extract ids and store in List of int using flutter.
I have try this code but not working.

```
Future<List<int>> fetchTopIds() async{

     final response = await client.get('$_baseUrl/posts?fields=id');
     final ids = json.decode(response.body); 
     return ids.cast<int>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
var intIds = ids.map<int>((m) => m['id'] as int).toList();
```

Comment: thanks but this show me error that the method map is not defined.

Comment: I think I mixed something up in your code. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

**This is what I did when got "array of object" as response** (I know I'm late. But it will help the next guy)

```
    List list = json.decode(response.body);

  if (response.body.contains("id")) {
    var lst = new List(list.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var idValue = list[i]['id'];
      print(idValuee);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I attached a complete example of converting a list to JSON and then retrieve the List back from that JSON.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {

  List<int> a= [1,2,3]; //List of Integer

  var json= jsonEncode(a); //json Encoded to String
  print(json.runtimeType.toString());

  var dec= jsonDecode(json); //Json Decoded to array of dynamic object

  print(dec.runtimeType.toString());


  a= (dec as List).map((t)=> t as int).toList(); //dynamic array mapped to integer List

  print(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better and easier way to get required information/ data from JSON Array.

Refer to https://pub.dev/packages/http/example to know more

Code to get a quick starts:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) async {
var url = 'ENTER YOUR API ENDPOINT';
var response = await http.get(url);
var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
var itemCount = jsonResponse['totalItems'];
print('Number of books about http: $itemCount.');
```

Here '**totalItems**' would be your desired key.This will only work if you get a response.statusCode == 200

Comment: But this does not deserialize JSON to list object. Count of items is not the only thing to do with list.

Comment: But If you have a json object {"book_name":"book1", "author_name","author1"}. You can access value of "book_name" and value of "author_name" i.e "book1" and "author1" respectively.

Comment: Yes, but the question was to turn JSON object with **array of objects with `id` field** to list of that same `id`s, not how to access single object property.

Comment: This you tube tutorial might help you achieve your desired goal https://youtu.be/LQAUmQFViAY

Comment: SO is not a forum, so it's not useful to provide links to some youtube tutorials, especially when there's a good answers with code snippets. I do not need to achieve something, the Questioner asked for the very precise task and expects to have answers for the question, but this is not about the OP's task. You can check this article for more info: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).